# jQuery JSONP request causing TFL API to throw 400

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm using jQuery .getJSON to get data from TFL's (transport for london) API.

However adding the ?callback=? parameter to the request causes the API to throw a 400 (Bad Request) error because it is very strict about what parameters it accepts. I.E the api can't recognise '?callback' as a valid parameter and therefore freaks out.

Is there another completely different way of doing this? Somehow getting the api response and parsing it myself for example. I'm new to JS and jQuery so apologies if I'm missing something super obvious!

```
var busStopAPI = 'http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?StopCode1=56094&VisitNumber=1&ReturnList=StopCode1,StopPointName,LineName,DestinationText,EstimatedTime,DirectionId';    
$.getJSON(busStopAPI, this.busStopSuccess).fail(this.busStopFailure);
```

p.s. I've tried the other .ajax() data types but they all throw 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add "**callback**" because you want to use **JSONP**, right?... and you want to do that because if you don't you get a **cross-domain error**, right?

I would suggest to create a **local web service proxy** in your server that calls TFL's api and supply data to your UI. In that way you do not have to use JSONP and do not have to worry about cross-domain issues. ([more info](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html))

FYI, there are other approaches, but I personally prefer a proxy service when the api does not support JSONP callbacks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah great yes thank you. I remember doing that to get around cross domain issues in ActionScript. Thanks for your help Daniel.